# Create virtual directory on blob storage VHD using WebRole

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7, azure, virtual-directory, vhd

I am interested to create virtual directories on blob storage VHD. First I consider the Hosted Web Core Web Role (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/hwcworker), but the author suggested that we should stick to Web Role as SDK 1.3 fully supported IIS7 (http://blog.smarx.com/posts/serving-your-website-from-a-windows-azure-drive), as:

[UPDATE 12/14/2010] Now that SDK 1.3 and above support full IIS, I don’t see why my HWC Worker solution is needed anymore. I’m leaving this and other blog posts up for those interested, but I’m not fixing any bugs. (There’s a typo in one bit of documentation and a bug preventing VHD uploads larger than 2GB. There are probably other issues I don’t know about, so consider yourself warned.)

How would we create virtual directory using just WebRole or setting which configurations file ? any link, tutorial or sample/example would be great.

EDIT: further clarification: our application consists of different components, one component is stored on WebRole, other components are required to store on azure drive, because those components can be very huge in size, such as 1 TB, as those are user submitted aspx scripts, which are pluggable aspx code, and become part of application. We need to create VirtualDirectory entry to make those aspx scripts in Azure Drive to be able to execute on server.

EDIT: more clarification: If I could be able to just use azure drive as virtualdirectory for serving web page, then I will modify it to our need.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I'm that author... what is it you're looking to do?  Do you want to store your website in a Windows Azure Drive?  Or are you just trying to add a virtual directory to a web role?

Comment: Thanks smarx for you response, our application consists of different components, one component is stored on WebRole, other components are required to store on azure drive, because those components can be very huge in size, such as 1 TB, as those are user submitted aspx scripts, which are pluggable aspx code, and become part of application. We need to create VirtualDirectory entry to make those aspx scripts in Azure Drive to be able to execute on server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out: WebRole in SDK 1.3 allow to host multiple websites on a single instance as specified in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg433110.aspx

In short, I made the entries in ServiceDefinition.csdef something as follows:

ServiceDefinition.csdef:

```
<ServiceDefinition ...
  <WebRole name=" ...
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web" physicalDirectory="{approot}\WebSite1">

...
```